# How do I disable a javascript event handler introduced by a 3rd party?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

My site is using a mouse signature tool:

http://www.realsignature.com/demo/default.aspx

It uses a canvas to capture the signature and render it to a jpeg.

Unfortunately there is a (terrible) chrome extension toolbar which breaks the mouse signature tool:

http://bittorrentbar.ourtoolbar.com/

From what I've been able to dig up, it looks like there is a mouse event handler which is capturing the mousedown / mouseup events in the toolbar and that is causing the trouble...but I'm not certain on that. My only hint is that chrome is throwing this warning up when there is a click event:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL chrome-    extension://mhfdcmehmjcclgopdodkjdicohagipid/Js/items/container/container.html#tabUrl=http:/    /localhost:1805 from frame with URL http://localhost:1805/secure/Confirm.aspx?    ID=MAYNHQHRXBQSDOKKYRMVWFRWAMSSQK. 
Domains, protocols and ports must match.
chrome-extension://cekbgkmeapobkbadclnkjfjdbpbcaobd/copier.js:278

getSelectedText chrome-extension://cekbgkmeapobkbadclnkjfjdbpbcaobd/copier.js:278

doMouseUp chrome-extension://cekbgkmeapobkbadclnkjfjdbpbcaobd/copier.js:91

(anonymous function)
```

I've tried over-riding the doMouseUp method with my own, tried to block the event from bubbling...but i'm not a javascript guru and nothing seems to be working. I've emailed the developers of the Signature tool and the toolbar with no response from either party.

Help me stop this evil mal-ware toolbar please!

Just to be clear, I'm not trying to solve this problem for myself...but for the thousands of people that use my site every week. They're the ones that have this toolbar installed, not me.

Comment: I think that is not your job to stop any evil malware toolbar. I mean this is a job of a program like comodo defence, norton antivirus etc. For some one help you with that you must go to your computer where chrome keep the extention and find the copier.js and place it here to see the line that have the problem. But the best think is to let user just disable this extensions.

Comment: I completely agree, but I'd like to have a better answer for the people that call in other than 'uninstall that crappy toolbar you have installed, and stop installing crap. moron'. Ideally I'd like to be able to block the toolbar's event handling so that the mouse signature works...but I haven't been able figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the extension is doing, but you can just disable and/or remove it from Chrome. Just go to Options > Tools > Extensions and uncheck the Enabled box. You can trash the extension as well if you don't have a need for it.

Comment: I think he is trying to allow users who have this toolbar installed to still be able to use his site.  If not... am I missing why you cant disable (as mentioned above) or uninstall?

Comment: I'm not trying to solve this issue for myself, it's the people using my website. I have several thousand people using my site every week, and a small percentage of them have this toolbar installed. I'd like to find some way to possibly disable this toolbar's javascript it's running so I can properly capture the mouse signature of my clients.